# Rollback YUM package

Tags: linux, yum, update

What's the best (ie foolproof and easy) mechanism for rolling back an rpm update using YUM?

I've not come across the problem where I upgrade something and later find I want to downgrade it, but I'd rather be prepared for when it does happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a fairly easy to follow procedure for doing it:  [Yum Rollback](http://blog.chris.tylers.info/index.php?/archives/17-How-to-Rollback-Package-UpdatesInstallation-on-Fedora.html)

It does involve making some configuration changes to yum, but seems pretty easy.  To summarize the link:

1. Add ‘tsflags=repackage’ to /etc/yum.conf
2. Add ‘%_repackage_all_erasures 1’ to /etc/rpm/macros

And when you want to rollback use the ‘--rollback’ flag within rpm.  Like I said, seems pretty brain dead easy.

Comment: now that really does look like the business. Why isn't that on by default?!

Comment: it's not by default because you have to have the old package for `rpm` or it won't work - rpms don't really "upgrade" or "patch", they reinstall with the new edition

Comment: This works on my CentOs but not on FC, do you know why ? I got a "--rollback: unknown option"

Comment: @Bastien974: It looks like rollback was removed with rpm-4.6.0 per http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.6.0#Removedfeatures You're probably using CentOS 5, which uses rpm-4.4.2. Most likely you're using a release of Fedora that includes rpm-4.6 or higher. (Note that F15 is at v4.9.1)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the --oldpackage switch with the older rpm:

```
rpm -Uvh foo.rpm --oldpackage
```